# Express optional route not found when deployed to Google App Engine

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've added a new optional parameter to a route in my Express service. Everything works locally, however when deployed to Google App Engine my service is returning a not found when the optional param is supplied.

Main server startup:

```
const indexRouter: express.Router = cradle.indexRouter; // from dependency injection
const server = express();
server.disable("x-powered-by");
server.use(responseTime(responseTimeLogger(logger)));
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(port, () => {
      logger.info(`Express server has started on port ${port}`);
      server.use("/api/v1/", indexRouter);
      resolve();
});
```

`cradle.indexRouter` -> `createIndexRouter`:

```
function createIndexRouter(services: IIndexRouterArgs) {
  const indexRouter = Router();

  indexRouter.use("/weather", services.weatherRouter);
  indexRouter.use("/health", services.healthRouter);
  indexRouter.use("*", notFoundMiddleware);

  return indexRouter;
}
```

`services.weatherRouter` -> `createWeatherRouter`:

```
function createWeatherRouter(services: IWeatherRouterArgs) {
  const weatherRouter = Router();

  weatherRouter.get(
    "/:latitude/:longitude/:postalCode?",
    services.weatherController.reportWeather
  );

  return weatherRouter;
}
```

Upon requesting `https://{service}.com/api/v1/weather/50/50/10001` I'm expecting to hit `services.weatherController.reportWeather` but am instead being routed to the `notFoundMiddleware` because of the 10001 (postalCode) param. Removing it returns a successful response.

Comment: what is the url you are requesting?

Comment: https://{service}.com/api/v1/weather/50/50/10001

Comment: where's the /api/v1 coming from? you need to post your complete setup

Comment: Just updated with some additional info

Comment: what do you get if you console.log `req.params`

Comment: Locally I get `{ latitude: '50', longitude: '-50', postalCode: '10001' }`. `services.weatherRouter` _is_ `createWeatherRouter()`. So it's passed to `indexRouter.use("/weather", services.weatherRouter)` and evaluates

Comment: you said it works when you don't include postalCode, so what are params when you don't include postal code?

Comment: https://{service}.com/api/v1/weather/50/50

Comment: Just deployed with the console.log in my notFoundMiddleware and it didn't even get hit. Does GAE do route scanning or something that would prevent the request from making it to the service?